# Gulp copy in VS 2015 not copying files

Tags: gulp, bower, asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET 5 template, starts with a gulpfile.js and several installed bower components.  I've added additional bower components (angularjs) and they are copied to my wwwroot\lib folder as expected.  I've added one of my own libraries to a folder I've called ext_modules\dist.  I am adding a task to gulpfile.js to copy my files (containing a single .js and a .css file) to the wwwroot\lib folder as well.  I'm following the example syntax already present in gulpfile.js.  However, nothing is ever copied from my ext_modules folder.  Please see the JS below, output, and folder structure.

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' />

var gulp = require("gulp"),
  rimraf = require("rimraf"),
  fs = require("fs");

eval("var project = " + fs.readFileSync("./project.json"));

var paths = {
    bower: "./bower_components/",
    extmodules: "./ext_modules/",
    lib: "./" + project.webroot + "/lib/"
};

gulp.task("clean", function (cb) {
  rimraf(paths.lib, cb);
});

gulp.task("copy", ["clean"], function () {
    var bower = {
        "angular": "angular.js/*.js",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap/dist/**/*.{js,map,css,ttf,svg,woff,eot}",
        "bootstrap-touch-carousel": "bootstrap-touch-carousel/dist/**/*.{js,css}",
        "hammer.js": "hammer.js/hammer*.{js,map}",
        "jquery": "jquery/jquery*.{js,map}",
        "jquery-validation": "jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js",
        "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
    };

    var extmodules = {
        "ext-modules": "dist/*.{js,map,css,ttf,svg,woff,eot}"
    };

    for (var module in bower) {  /* This copy works fine*/
        console.log("Source: " + paths.bower + bower[module]);
        console.log("Destination: " + paths.lib + module);
        gulp.src(paths.bower + bower[module])
          .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.lib + module));
    };

    for (var module in extmodules) {  /* This does not copy any files */
        console.log("Source: " + paths.extmodules + extmodules[module]);
        console.log("Destination: " + paths.lib + module);
        gulp.src(paths.extmodules + extmodules[module])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.lib + module));
    };
});
```

Here is my console log:

```
[11:17:57] Starting 'clean'...
[11:17:57] Finished 'clean' after 11 ms
[11:17:57] Starting 'copy'...
Source: ./bower_components/angular.js/*.js
Destination: ./wwwroot/lib/angular
Source: ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/**/*.{js,map,css,ttf,svg,woff,eot}
Destination: ./wwwroot/lib/bootstrap
Source: ./bower_components/bootstrap-touch-carousel/dist/**/*.{js,css}
Destination: ./wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-touch-carousel
Source: ./bower_components/hammer.js/hammer*.{js,map}
Destination: ./wwwroot/lib/hammer.js
Source: ./bower_components/jquery/jquery*.{js,map}
Destination: ./wwwroot/lib/jquery
Source: ./bower_components/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js
Destination: ./wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation
Source: ./bower_components/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
Destination: ./wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive
Source: ./ext_modules/dist/*.{js,map,css,ttf,svg,woff,eot}
Destination: ./wwwroot/lib/ext-modules
[11:17:57] Finished 'copy' after 21 ms
Process terminated with code 0.
```

[image: VSSolutionExplorer]

Comment: With `./ext_modules/dist` not expanded in your screenshot, I can't tell what files are in it... were you maybe intending to include all files in subfolders of `./ext_modules/dist`, too? (`"ext-modules": "dist/**/*.{js,map,css,ttf,svg,woff,eot}"`)

Comment: dist contains only 2 files.  A js and css file.  No folders.  I have also tried the ** syntax.

Comment: Ouch. My next suggestion was to run it from the command line, but since it's working now... Do you have it triggered through a watch? I know that can be cached...

Answer (score 1):

I can get this to work if I explicitly right mouse on the gulpfile.js and select "Task Runner Explorer" then a window shows docked to the bottom.  in the Tasks will be a list of tasks.  You can then right mouse on the task you want to run and select "Run".